# send JSON data with post and JWS

Tags: php, python, http, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp (and asyncio) to make a POST request to a PHP application.
When I set the header for json on python the PHP application do not receive any $_POST data (PHP have `Content-Type: application/json` header setted).

The php side code just returns the `json_encode($_POST)`.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import simplejson as json
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from aiohttp import Timeout

h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = "https://url.php"
d = {'some': 'data'}
d = json.dumps(d)
# send JWS cookie
cookies = dict(sessionID='my-valid-jws')


async def send_post():
    with Timeout(5):
        async with ClientSession(cookies=cookies, headers=h) as session:
            async with session.post(url, data=d) as response:
                if (response.status == 200):
                    response = await response.json()
                    print(response)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(send_post())
```

Running this I got: `[]`

When removing the headers param and the `json.dump(d)` I get: `{"some:"data"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP won't understand `application/json` by default, you have to implement it yourself, typically by dropping something like:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]) &&
    strncmp($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"], "application/json", strlen("application/json")) === 0)
{
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
    if ($_POST === NULL) /* By default PHP never gives NULL in $_POST */
        $_POST = []; /* So let's not change old habits. */
}
```

In a "common load path" of your PHP code.

Comment: I set the header, you can see the code here: https://github.com/edoz90/SimpleRest/blob/master/lib/Rest.inc.php.
I'll try how do you suggest.

Comment: Yes, setting an `application/json` as `Content-Type` header is mandatory for my snipet to work, which is normal and natural: "if it's json, decode it'.

Comment: @edoz90 Oh you're completly right, I fix it, thanks.